# Spark Scala: How to update each column of a DataFrame in correspondence with each position of a Vector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DF like this:

```
+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
|               col_0|col_1|               col_2|
+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
|0.009069428120139292|  0.3|9.015488712438252E-6|
|0.008070826019024355|  0.4|3.379696051366339...|
|0.009774715414895803|  0.1|1.299590589291292...|
|0.009631155146285946|  0.9|1.218569739510422...|
```

And two Vectors:

```
v1[7.0,0.007,0.052]
v2[804.0,553.0,143993.0]
```

The total number of columns is the same as the total number of position in each vector.
How can apply an equation using the numbers saved in the ith position to make some computation to update the current value of the DF (in the ith position)? I mean, I need to update all values in the DF,  using the values in the vectors.

Comment: can you give us concrete examples of what that computation would be ? an expected dataframe would do as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark ML: Data de-normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50279674/9613318)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I couldn't add that information before, but in the answer that user2682459 gave me there is a good example.

Comment: if that answer helped you then you should consider upvote and accepting that answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is what you're after?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

val df = Seq((1,2,3),(4,5,6)).toDF

val updateVector = Vector(10,20,30)

val updateFunction = (columnValue: Column, vectorValue: Int) => columnValue * lit(vectorValue)

val updateColumns = (df: DataFrame, updateVector: Vector[Int], updateFunction:((Column, Int) => Column)) => {
    val columns = df.columns
    updateVector.zipWithIndex.map{case (updateValue, index) => updateFunction(col(columns(index)), updateVector(index)).as(columns(index))}
}

val dfUpdated = df.select(updateColumns(df, updateVector, updateFunction) :_*)

dfUpdated.show

+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
| 10| 40| 90|
| 40|100|180|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Just a note - `updateVector` is probably `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector`

Comment: @user6910411 Never used ml but a quick look at linalg.Vector suggests that my answer would be very easy to adapt. If the OP clarifies I'll happily update it :)